# how to detect the group separated by space

Tags: java

There is a string,`string a="  *|** ||      |**|** ";`

The space separated this string into three groups. How can I converse these three groups into an array with three elements?

I tried to use split,

```
String a="  *|** ||      |**|** ";
String names[]=a.trim().split(" ");
System.out.println(names.length);
```

The expected output should be 3, however, it shows 8. Anyone who can tell me how to do it? thanks

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**?

Comment: Please show the `split` code that you've tried, along with the expected output you need and the incorrect output you received.

Comment: I think you're expecting [trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to do more than "Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String a="  *|** ||      |**|** ";
String names[]=a.trim().split("\\s+");
System.out.println(names.length);
```

This splits by any amount of white space characters (regular spaces, tabs, etc)

The regex `"\\s+"` searches for any white space.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting on multiple spaces, your code splits on a single space character. \s+ is regex for 1 or more spaces.

```
String a = "  *|** ||      |**|** ";
String names[] = a.trim().split("\\s+");
System.out.println(names.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
```

Output

```
3
[*|**, ||, |**|**]
```